# How can I get a String with UTC time in Java 6?

Tags: java, date, utc

I'm trying to get the current time in a String with the UTC format: 2022-05-19T18:20:53.480Z. However, I have to use jdk 6 and I'm having trouble finding the way to do it. Does anybody know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in that post they use classes that are not available in Java 6, such as DateTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Generate text:

```
org.threeten.bp.Instant.now().toString()
```

Parse text:

```
org.threeten.bp.Instant.parse( "2022-05-19T18:20:53.480Z" )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The legacy date-time classes found in Java 6 are *terribly* flawed. Avoid `Date`, `Calendar`, etc.

## *ThreeTen-Backport*

Use only *java.time* classes found in Java 8 and later. For Java 6 and 7, add the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library to your project. This brings you most of the *java.time* functionality in nearly the same API.

Your input string’s format complies with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The standard formats are used by default in *java.time* when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

The `Z` on the end in your input string indicates an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. A moment in UTC (an offset of zero) is represented by [Instant](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2022-05-19T18:20:53.480Z" ) ;
```

---

Of course, I should add the obligatory caution that Java 6 is long past end-of-life. Using Java 6 without a paid support program providing updates is risky business. I strongly recommend you move to an [LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) version of Java: [versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) 8, 11, and 17.